# Intel hd4000 + Nvidia geforce 710m

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, asus, intel

Translated to English using Google:

I bought a notebook asus f552cl that has the ability to use either the integrated video card or video card intel nvidia geforce 710m with optimus technology. Now on ubuntu 12.04 (the only one that does not give me problems with the network adapter atheros), is used only the intel integrated card, but I would always use the nvidia. How do I install the drivers for the nvidia card and make it usable by default? Thanks and sorry for the problem possibly even stupid

---

Original question:

> Ho comprato un notebook asus f552cl che ha la possibilità di utilizzare o la scheda video integrata intel o la scheda video nvidia geforce 710m grazie alla tecnologia optimus. Ora su ubuntu 12.04 (l'unico che non mi da problemi con la scheda di rete atheros), viene utilizzata solo la scheda intel integrata, mentre io vorrei utilizzare sempre la nvidia. Come devo fare ad installare i driver per la scheda nvidia e renderla utilizzabile di default? Grazie e scusate per il problema possibilmente anche stupido

Comment: English is the only language allowed here. Please take help of translator if required.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Install bumblebee (via a PPA as you're on 12.04): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Power_Management

2) Nvidia proprietary drivers now (partially) support Optimus, which you can enable with nvidia-prime as described here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html. Please note however that in this case you won't (yet) be able to switch to the Intel chip for powersaving.

I know the issue has been discussed on this site before but it was mostly pre-nvidia-prime, and even if I'd personally prefer bumblebee, it would be fair to mention both options.